# extract specific value from dictionary of list of dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, extract, sublist

I have dataset like this:

```
{'project-1': [{'id':'1','name':'john'},{'id':'20','name':'steve'}],
 'project-2': [{'id':'6','name':'jack'},{'id':'42','name':'anna'}]}
```

what I want to extract is the name of all people:

```
['john','steve','jack','anna']
```

How to get these list using python?

Comment: just a clarification, you don't have a list of lists, it's a dictionary of list of dictionaries

Comment: Yes, you're right. Thanks for clarify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my_dict = {
    'project-1': [{'id':'1','name':'john'},{'id':'20','name':'steve'}],
    'project-2': [{'id':'6','name':'jack'},{'id':'42','name':'anna'}]
}
```

You can use a list comprehension it get the `name` field from each dictionary contained within the sublists (i.e. within the values of the original dictionary).

```
>>> [d.get('name') for sublists in my_dict.values() for d in sublists]
['john', 'steve', 'jack', 'anna']
```

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over the dict, then over the values of the current dict:

```
for d_ in d.values():
    for item in d_:
        print item['name']
```

Or in comprehension

```
names = [item['name'] for d_ in d.values() for item in d_]
print names
['john', 'steve', 'jack', 'anna']
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.

```
d = {'project-1': [{'id':'1','name':'john'},{'id':'20','name':'steve'}],
     'project-2': [{'id':'6','name':'jack'},{'id':'42','name':'anna'}]}
result = list()
for key in d:
    for x in d[key]:
        result.append(x['name'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Many solutions trying same old approach here using `two loop`:

Here is different approach:

> One line solution without any loop:

You can use lambda function with map:

```
data={'project-1': [{'id':'1','name':'john'},{'id':'20','name':'steve'}],
 'project-2': [{'id':'6','name':'jack'},{'id':'42','name':'anna'}]}



print(list(map(lambda x:list(map(lambda y:y['name'],x)),data.values())))
```

output:

```
[['john', 'steve'], ['jack', 'anna']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
name_id = {'project-1': [{'id':'1','name':'john'},{'id':'20','name':'steve'}], 'project-2': [{'id':'6','name':'jack'},{'id':'42','name':'anna'}]}

name_id['project-1'][0]['name'] = 'john'
name_id['project-1'][1]['name'] = 'steve'
name_id['project-2'][0]['name'] = 'jack'
name_id['project-2'][1]['name'] = 'anna'
```

The `['project-1']` gets the value corresponding to the `project-1` key in the dictionary `name_id`. `[0]` is the list index for the first element in the dictionary value. `['name']` is also a key, but of the dictionary in the first element of the list. It gives you the final value that you want.